# OpenCV partition() underlying algorithm

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, cluster-analysis

Does anybody know what algorithm is used [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/clustering.html#partition)?

I want to implement this function to do detection's windows grouping.

Thank you.

Comment: OpenCV is open source. Why not have a look?

Comment: @RogerRowland yes, I know :)
But it would be great to know what algorithm do they use first.
What I want to do is to implement this thing in a different language and first I want to know the name of the algorithm (maybe there are libraries that might have it implemented) before porting it to another language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the OpenCV source code for the `partition` function, you will see the following comments:

```
// This function splits the input sequence or set into one or more equivalence classes and
// returns the vector of labels - 0-based class indexes for each element.
// predicate(a,b) returns true if the two sequence elements certainly belong to the same class.
//
// The algorithm is described in "Introduction to Algorithms"
// by Cormen, Leiserson and Rivest, the chapter "Data structures for disjoint sets"
template<typename _Tp, class _EqPredicate> int partition( const vector<_Tp>& _vec, vector<int>& labels, _EqPredicate predicate=_EqPredicate())
{
    // ... etc.
}
```

This gives you both the source code, and the reference for the algorithm.

So, that's Chapter 21 [in this book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Introduction-Algorithms-Thomas-H-Cormen/dp/0262033844).

Comment: Great!
Thank you, Roger.

Could you, please, refer me where did you find this lines?

Because I found only this
https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/b46719b0931b256ab68d5f833b8fadd83737ddd1/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/operations.hpp#L438

Comment: @warmspringwinds Maybe they removed the comment in later sources - I have 2.4.8 and the body of that function looks the same to me. For example, [you can see it here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/commit/d58cadc1ea9e25a0332fcb883225dab89cc1a835)

Comment: Thank you :)
Now it's much easier for me with this information.